# React data grid autocomplete editor throwing invalid prop error for null fields

Tags: reactjs, react-data-grid

My react data grid component has an autocomplete editor on a field. When a cell contains a value and is clicked in, the drop down and type-to-select work as expected.  When the cell contains a null value, clicking in the cell throws the following error:

```
Warning: `value` prop on `input` should not be null. Consider using an empty string to clear the component or `undefined` for uncontrolled components.
```

How to best get rid of this error?